Can you get a polyline from OSRM that respects the order of the waypoints?
Is there a way of using OSRM to get a polyline route geometry that runs through a list of waypoints without reordering them? In my tests, OSRM tends to reorder the waypoints.

The route service should return your routes in the same order as you supplied them, while the trip service should recalculate them using its traveling salesman (and other) heuristic algorithms. I would love to hear if the route service is not behaving as specified in the API documentation, as we are now building this feature into our platform. See the description of the Route and Trip services in this API documentation
